# DDD Strategic design: Shared kernel pattern vs Published language pattern

Tags: domain-driven-design, strategy-pattern

What are the key differentials between the shared-kernel and published-language strategic patterns opted in Domain driven design (DDD)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `shared-kernel` and `published-language` are part of the Context Maps patterns collection. Context Mapping is a very useful and powerful tool that allows one to see what kind of dependencies link systems together. They can also highlight teams relationships.
A `shared-kernel` means that 2 systems are strongly coupled by sharing a shared artifact (model, DLL, Jar, DB, ...). If those 2 systems are handled by 2 different teams, it means that whenever Team A change something, it will impact Team B and vice versa.
A `published-language` is a model that is well documented that everyone can understand and translate. Think of iCal, VCard or such things.
[Michael Plöd](https://twitter.com/bitboss) did a great job on documenting Context Maps patterns, you can have a look [here](https://github.com/ddd-crew/context-mapping/).

Answer (score 1):

They are completely different things.

Shared kernel basically is a model shared by two bounded context.

Published language often goes together with the open host service pattern, and is a well known language, used to define the offered services. For example, JSON or XML.